# How To Fix WordPress Cross Browser Compatibility?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html

I am using a  WordPress theme integration for a booking form and it is not working on iOS Devices. When the submit button is clicked it just refreshing the current page.

Any Ideas on how to fix this error?

I expect the code to be added in booking form for working fine

Visit "http://test.platinumcabs.com"

Comment: You are using any plugin for form?

Comment: nope its theme inbuild form

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){

setTimeout(function() {
  /* with this line, I pretend to disable both buttons in order to 
     prevent the user click them while the form is submitted */
  $('.btn-modal').attr('disabled', "disabled");

  /* show the gift image */
  $('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');

}, 1);

});
```

Hope its work for you